# Basic Authentication on AngularJS via $resource

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem, I am a newbie on AngularJS, for a Rest service, I need to authenticate the user but the object is empty.

The first reference to User.mail is empty but on the alert box, I have the real value.

Have you any idea please ?

```
.factory('Rest', ['$rootScope', '$resource', 'UserService', function($rootScope, $resource, User){
    return $resource($rootScope.services.url + ':serviceId/:itemId/', {}, {
        /** One element **/
        get: {
            method:'GET',
            headers:{
                Authorization: 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(User.mail + ':' + User.password),
                Accept: 'text/xml'
                }, 
            params:{serviceId:'', itemId:''}, 
            transformResponse: function(data) {
                alert('mail : ' + User.mail);
                var response = XmlToJson.init(data);
                if(response.length > 0) 
                    return response[0];/*in this case xmlToJson returns an array with one element*/
                else
                    return {};
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `transformResponse` in `$resource` doesn't actually deserailize JSON into objects (which the docs say it's supposed to do). The object will be available in the transformResponse method, but not when the $resource service returns.

You need to use the `$http` service and its `transformResponse` to get the behaviour you're looking for.  For example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3FNGYu)

For a full explanation see [AngularJS transformResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515481/angularjs-transformresponse).