# AngularJS transformResponse

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

In angularjs resource, I would like to convert my json data into JS objects

```
//Complex object with inheritance chain
function Car(year, make){
    this.make = make;
    this.year = year;
}


var carResource = $resource("/api/car/id", {id: '@id'},
    {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter){
                return new Car(data.make, data.year);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

However this does not seem to be happening

What I am getting back is a `$resource` object meaning that the properties `make` and `year` are set correctly, however the prototype of the returned object points to `$resource`

Is there a way where I can map my json data directly to my own objects?

Or will I have to write my own 'resource' implementation?

Comment: Take a look to decorator http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide

Comment: Why do you use $resource if you want your own classes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### `transformResponse` is executed on `$http` level.

When you customise $resource actions with custom config object, that object is actually passed on to the underlying `$http` service. So if you specify a `transformResponse` callback, it will be executed on `$http` level, and the results of your transformation will be passed back on to $resource.

$resource service will instantiate new object from your response data (which is already transformed by the `transformResponse` callback) and this new object will be an instance of the $resource itself.

So, your `car` object **will** be an instance of the `Car`, but only for a moment, until it's properties are copied into a new `$resource` object.

Here's a simplistic view of the process:

1. $resource service initiates request
2. $http service sends request and receives the response
3. $http service transforms the response (response is now instance of `Car`)
4. $resource service receives the transformed response (from $http)
5. $resource service makes an instance of itself using transformed response properties (result is now instance of $resource)

Anyway, I don't recommend decorating or extending the $resource service, because it's simpler to write your own implementation using $http service.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the purpose of the transformResponse method and actually thought I could change what the `$resource` returns. A simple wrapper around $http service would be good enough for me.

Comment: Maybe to use resource interceptor
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11409