# I have to read the Location header, but transformResponse in $resource is not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have the following `$resouce` service:

```
$scope.scenesResource = $resource(scenesUrl + ':lang/:id', {
                                      lang: '@lang',
                                      id: '@id'
                                  }, {
                                      create: {
                                           method: 'POST',
                                           headers: {
                                              Authorization: localStorage.tokenType + ' ' + localStorage.accessToken 
                                           },
                                           transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
                                                //This is never getting called
                                                console.log(data); 
                                                console.log(headers);
                                           }
                                      }
                                  };
```

Despite any security issues, such as reading the access token from local storage, or never expiring it, the `create` method works fine.

I mean, it makes a request with the correct `Authorization` header, and gets a `201 Created` response from the server.

The problem is that, the server, instead of responding with the new resource's id in the response body or payload, it returns the `Location` header:

```
Location: /scenes/en-us/ODc1ZmYwNzUtZDA5MS00ZWJkLTgyODYtZWUzMGMyMDdhMmYx
```

I have a promise function on the `create` method:

```
newResource.$create().then(function (newScene) {
    //Handle scene
});
```

As you can see, I need `newScene` to be filled with all the information that the server responded so I can handle it properly. But this information is in the `Location` header.

I am unable to read this header using the `transformResponse` method above in the example, because the method is never getting called.

How can I read my `Location` header using `$resource`?

Comment: try to read this post if you haven't read yet http://stackoverflow.com/a/17903447/3316654

Comment: @wilver That works if you're using `$httpProvider`. but I am using the `$resource` service.

Comment: $resource depends on $http and $http make the transformResponse at its own level. You can also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515481/angularjs-transformresponse or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455387/resource-transformresponse-not-working. Which version of Angular.js are you using?

Comment: I have read the questions but can't solve my problem still. I know about `transformResponse` being executed in an `$http` level, and in fact I am using it in my question. The problem is it's not executing. I have the latest AngularJS version.

Comment: Can you return a 200 or 202 http status code from server call? If so, you get the same behaviour? try to look at this: http://www.trajano.net/2013/05/201-created-with-angular-resource/

Comment: have you resolved the problem?

Comment: @wilver Yes, thank you very much for your support. I removed the `transformResponse` method from the `$create` definition and instead passed in a callback function to the `$create` call on the resource. This callback function is given the headers I need. For example: `newResource.$create(function (data, headers) { var location = headers('Location'); })`